# What Maven dependency to add to include java.sql.Date for Java 17?

Tags: java

What is the dependency to add to `pom.xml` in order to get rid of this:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/sql/Date
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:445)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:587)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
```

I'm with Java 17, but my production platform is with Java 8. So, I need a dependency, not a Java 9 module. Please don't suggest changing my dev or prod environments. I do understand that it would be the best option.

Comment: You shouldn't need a Maven import, `java.sql.Date` is still part of the JDK. Your error message mentions `java.base` which means that you're currently using the module system. You'll need to require module `java.sql`. That may only be necessary for Java 17, so maybe you can do that with some command-line flags.

Comment: @RobSpoor I want my `pom.xml` to compile with both Java 8 and Java 17. If I add command line args, it will stop working with Java 8. I'm looking for a solution similar to this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/43574427/187141

Comment: Java 8 has passed the end of its support life.  I would recommend LTS versions 11 and 17, nothing else.

Comment: @RobSpoor if `java.sql.Date` would be part of JDK, I think it would exist in the classpath and `URLClassLoader` would find it. Or I miss something?

Comment: Your development environment isn't sane, when it's not compatible with production. Common sense may suggest to simply use Java 8 or 11 for development. Either downgrade the development environment or upgrade the production environment. Everything else is  highly questionable.

Comment: Do you have a module-info.java in your project? Then either remove it if you don't want to use modular java, or add `requires java.sql;` to it if you want to use JDBC. As others have mentioned, `java.sql.Date` is part of the Java standard library. It is also possible your code is doing some odd classloading, but in that case you will need to post a [mre].

Comment: I strongly recommend you don’t use `java.sql.Date`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `LocalDate` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). You may have known this already, but the comment should stand here for other users who may not be aware.

Comment: The only place where you should be using java.sql.Date is for relational database code.  The java.time package should be preferred.